# I want to send the PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, *.pdf ) as the file attachment in the email... How can I accomplish that?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email, itext

This is using iTextSharp to create the file from a button click after having filled in the formFieldMaps....   I want to attach the resulting generated pdf to the email being created.... Any help would be appreciated....

```
var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);
PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-" + txtInsured.Text + "-PNREIGSFL0412.pdf");

var doc = new Document();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
//doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();
memoryStream.Position = 0;

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("email@website1.com", "email@website2.com")
{
    Subject = "subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "body"
};

mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "Completed-" + txtInsured.Text + "-PNREIGSFL0412.pdf"));
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost"); 
//SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
//{
//    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
//    Port = 587,
//    EnableSsl = true,
//    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
//
//};

client.Send(mm);
```

So heres a snippet of the  start of the generate button code....

```
protected void btnGeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/SG-8385PNREISGSFL0412.pdf"));
    string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
    var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
    {
        formFieldMap["form1[0].#subform[0].header[0].TextField1[0]"] = txtInsured.Text;
        formFieldMap["form1[0].#subform[0].header[0].NumericField1[1]"] = txtInsSSN.Text;
        if (ddlProtocol.SelectedValue != "1")
        {
            formFieldMap["funeralorcrem"] = ddlProtocol.SelectedItem.Text;
            formFieldMap["refrigeration"] = "No Embalming *Refrigeration Required*";
            formFieldMap["form1[0].#subform[0].SectionA[0].TextField24[1]"] = "Refrigeration required for cremation.";
        }
        else
```

then there is a pile of code that fills in more fields using logic and the formFieldMap

and finally we get to the ReturnPDF

```
        var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);
        PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-" + txtInsured.Text + "-PNREIGSFL0412.pdf");

        var doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
        //doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("email@website1.com", "email@website2.com")
        {
            Subject = "subject",
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = "body"
        };

        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "Completed-" + txtInsured.Text + "-PNREIGSFL0412.pdf"));
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost"); 
        //SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        //{
        //    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        //    Port = 587,
        //    EnableSsl = true,
        //    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
        //
        //};

        client.Send(mm);
```

that's where I am at.....   Thank you folks for the assist....

Comment: Do you have any error message? What is the result? The email isn't sent; the email is sent but without attachement; the email is sent but the attachment is unreadable?

Comment: You probably should replace `doc` by `pdfContents`. Currently it looks like you'll send a PDF containing only "First Paragraph". It's hard to say without seeing the code of `GeneratePDF` and `ReturnPDF`.

Comment: Gabriel - you are exactly correct the GeneratePDF and ReturnPDF fill formfields on a fillable file that I am calling... the filled form gets presented to be opened or saved... that form is stored in pdfContents and I want to attach it to the email.... I also want to store it to a SQL table... not sure how that will work yet...

Comment: Are you able to send the email now? If not you'll need to provide more details (start by answering the questions Biri asked you).

Comment: The email does get sent .... that code works ..... its just not getting the generated pdf into the email .... so my end game is to get the pdfHelper RetunPDF result into the email as an attachment.... and additionally get it stored in my sql table for later manipulation.

Comment: I am still looking for ideas on this one.....

Comment: did you get this figured out? im in the same boat.